# How to open program from process id?

Tags: java, process

Is there any way to open program which is running in background.
I've developed an application in java for ubuntu and want to open that application through its pid if it is already being running just like skype, skype is not create new instance if it is already running whethere clicks from the launcher(menu) insted of new instance it reopen same process.

Comment: do you mean **switch** to background program? and run in foreground?

Comment: You mean to stop it or control it (connect)?

Comment: check out this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/331534/resume-a-process-via-a-pid-number

Comment: @KasiyA yes sir, adjactly

Comment: @Mitch The recent edit clarifies this question is not actually about job control, as I'd thought it was. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'll vote to close. This becomes a generic Linux programming question then.

Comment: @muru A question about how to find and change focus to an application window seems like the sort of thing we tend to allow. We'll see how the votes fall.

Comment: @EliahKagan still generic Linux (as in [unix.se]). As you say, though.

Comment: As shown repeatedly in the comments, the OP only cares about Java-based solutions. I really don't see anything Ubuntu-specific here.

Comment: Bro! this problem is directly releated to ubuntu because there is no any other way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [@Peter.O's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45173/72456) and question by [@Omid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/switch-to-an-application-using-its-pid) in http://Unix.stackexchange.com, if you get the PID of the program that you know which program it is, then with follow command you can switch to you desired program:

for example if you take PID of firefox with [pidof](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/pidof.8.php) command, like `pidof firefox`, you get the result something like `3547`, then pass this PID to below command and switch to your program that you are used its PID:

```
wmctrl -ia $(wmctrl -lp | awk -vpid=$PID '$3==3547 {print $1; exit}')
```

Comment: +1 thank you sir, It opens program through pid. Now is it possible to implement in java? what happen if wmctrl not already installed  in computer?

Comment: @user2271502 the program that you want to open it MUST already opened before if you want to open it with its PID, as I said you need to get its PID and call above command(in answer) and use that in your program.

Comment: @user2271502 for your second Q in above comment read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl) and [here](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) and also [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272232/what-are-the-alternatives-to-wmctrl)

Comment: any other commandline interface like wmctrl which is already in ubuntu, just like skype, skype not ask any enviroment that should install before its install to implement this feature?

Comment: @user2271502 It's hardly to understand what exactly you want. skype doesn't use any PID to switch to itself.

Comment: sorry for the language, any other tool like wmctrl which is already installed in ubuntu?

Comment: @user2271502 read again [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/526625/how-to-open-program-from-process-id/526831?noredirect=1#comment718215_526831) I also mentioned alternative

Answer (score 2):

If you have already typed a command and forgot to use the `&`, you can put a foreground job into the background by typing ^Z (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) to suspend the job, followed by `bg` to put it into the background:

```
$ sleep 99
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 99
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 99 &
```

You can bring a background job into the foreground, so that the shell waits for it again, using `fg`:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 99 
$ fg
sleep 99
```

You can list the jobs of the current shell using the jobs command.

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 99
```

[[source]](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12f/notes/770_processes_and_jobs.html)

If you want to run spacial job in foreground/background just use process id to move it to foreground/background. see this example:

```
$ sleep 99     # run first job
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 99
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 99 &
$ sleep 1000   # run second job
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 1000
$ jobs         # view all jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 99 &
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 1000
$ bg %2        # move jobs number 2 to run in background
[2]+ sleep 1000 &
$ jobs         # view all jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 99 &
[2]+  Running                 sleep 1000 &
```

Both of jobs are running in background.

```
$ fg %2      #switch to second job and run it in foreground

  sleep 1000      #sleep 1000 is now running in foreground
```

Note: You need to kill these jobs by using `kill %processID`.

example: `kill %2` (kill second job with process ID #2)

Comment: thank you sir, for your comment. even I din't know what is foreground and background process, now its far cleared to me. But I've developed an application in java for ubuntu and want to open that application through its pid if it is already being running just like skype, skype is not create new instance if it is already running whethere clicks from the launcher(menu) insted of new instance it reopen same process.